# AngularJs Multiple Slide Carousel but 1 item per slide

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to use AngularJS and bootstrap to build carousel multiple item but 1 item per slide.

Exactly same as this. 
Please have a look here. http://www.bootply.com/94452, but I don't want to use jquery.

I've already looked many carousel but 1 item per slide.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [Carousel with AngularJS and Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel)

You can customize it. Nobody will write all code. I think that is what you need